# How best to access a file from resources folder

Tags: java, io, java-11

In a java project I need to access a file from the resources folder. I am able to do so in the following 3 ways:

```
// 1
new File("src/main/resources/a.txt")
// 2
new URL("file:src/main/resources/a.txt")
// 3
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("a.txt")
```

All these approaches seem to work. Is any of these approaches preferential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third one is the only one that will work once your program will be packaged (Jar or War).

Comment: With some gotchas: `getClass()` returns the actual class of the object, which might be a subclass, different from the code containing the statement. Unless you *want* to make the lookup depending on the potentially unknown subclass, you should rather use `Containing.class.getResource("/a.txt")`. Note that this further does not go through `getClassLoader()`, as using the class loader removes context information that can become important once you turn to Java modules. You usually want to locate a resource in your class’ module which is another reason not to use `getClass()`…